# Easy way to create an installation USB

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, downloads, md5sum, checksums

Unetbootin and other scripts are too much of a hassle, and `dd` is just plain scary. How can an unenlightened user like me create an Ubuntu installation USB using intuitive, colorful graphical tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the ISO image corresponding to your desired version.
2. Verify the MD5 or SHA1 checksum. (or don't. Who really does, anyway?)
3. Go to the USB drive in GNOME disk utility.
4. Unmount all partitions of the drive in question.
5. From the drop-down menu of the gear icon at the top right, follow the "restore image" wizard with the ISO you downloaded.